# how do I "build" a distribution from a list of values and then calculate p-values?

Tags: r, distributions, p-value

I have a list of values (A) that I consider to be the null distribution which I want to use to test the significance of another set of values (B) and get p-value for each item in B. I read this post [Calculating p-value from an arbitrary distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/calculating-p-value-from-an-arbitrary-distribution) but I still don't know how to do it in R or other platform... can someone give me some links or pointers on how to do it?

Edit:
the question I'm trying to answer is given a list of genes, whose expression are most variable among a group of people. You can imagine I have a big matrix with each row representing a gene and each column representing a sample. So I have many genes and many samples. I want to find out those genes that show variation (I don't know the variation characteristics yet). I have now a list of genes who I defined as invariable (basically all of their values are above 0.8 for example) I thought I can calculate the variance for these genes and consider them as a null distribution. And then I can use this null distribution to test my genes of interest on their variance and get a p-value for each gene's variance. So in the end, I thought i could get a list of genes with significant p-value (or corrected p-value with some multiple testing correction).

Comment: mpiktas' answer included R code. How does his `pF <- function(q) integrate(dF,-Inf,q)$value` not address the problem?

Comment: how does pF <- function(q)integrate(dF,-Inf,q)$value consider my actual values? i'm not getting it..

Comment: Your particular description of your situation doesn't make sense to me. Can you clarify what you're doing? I mean without using any jargon, like 'p-value', or 'significance'. What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: OK, the question I'm trying to answer is given a list of genes, whose expression are most variable among a group of people. You can imagine I have a big matrix with each row representing a gene and each column representing a sample. So I have many genes and many samples. I want to find out those genes that show variation (I don't know the variation characteristics yet). I have now a list of genes who I defined as invariable (basically all of their values are above 0.8 for example) I thought I can calculate the variance for these genes and consider them as a null distribution

Comment: And then I can use this null distribution to test my genes of interest on their variance and get a p-value for each gene's variance. So in the end, I thought i could get a list of genes with significant p-value (or corrected p-value with some multiple testing correction), that's basically what I'm thinking..

Comment: i got a little bit from the code in mpiktas's answer. essentially he built a normal distribution cumulative density function? what if my distribution is not a normal distribution..