# calculate p-values based on an arbitrary distribution

Tags: r, p-value

I have bootstrapped a distribution of values that is non-normal. Now I would like to calculate the p-value of a parameter mu against that distribution (i.e. how likely, given the bootstrapped distribution, is it to receive mu). Using example data [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807398/how-to-generate-distributions-given-mean-sd-skew-and-kurtosis-in-r?rq=1)

```
require(SuppDists)

## make a weird dist with Kurtosis and Skew
a <- rnorm( 5000, 0, 2 )
b <- rnorm( 1000, -2, 4 )
c <- rnorm( 3000,  4, 4 )
babyGotKurtosis <- c( a, b, c )
```

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/calculating-p-value-from-an-arbitrary-distribution) threat gives the intution to find the probability density function numerically. For a normal, they propose:

```
mu = 1.64

dF <- function(x)dnorm(x)
pF <- function(q)integrate(dF,-Inf,q)$value 

> pF(mu)
[1] 0.9494974
> pnorm(mu)
[1] 0.9494974
```

Just how to apply this approach to a simulated non-normal distribution?

Comment: The answer you linked works for the general case - normal is used only for an illustration that it gives the expected result.

Comment: Excactly, and the question I am posing myself is how to adapt this approach to a given non-normal distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the *empirical cumulative distribution function*, which simply returns which proportion of a sample is less than a given cutoff. In R, use `ecdf()`:

```
> xx <- rnorm(100)
> ecdf(xx)(2)
[1] 0.99
```

To get a p-value, you will need to do some judicious subtraction from one, taking absolute values and/or division by or multiplication by two, depending on whether you are looking for a one-sided or a two-sided test.